How to manually kern the first character in enumerate to imitate microtype?
This \kern does not move the quotation mark to the left. What am I doing wrong?
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kern-0.2em``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'' Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\\
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



You are in vertical mode, so the kern moves things up, use \leavevmode\kern.... to get a horizontal kern

\hspace{-0.2em} also works.

@jlab yes but doesn't explain "what am I doing wrong" with the kern

You right. I just wanted to suggest an alternative.
